# Does the 'unmanaged' Constraint in C# Relate to Unmanaged Resources and the Garbage Collector?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, computer-science, unmanaged

I've been studying the `unmanaged` constraint in C#, and it raised a question in my mind: Is the `unmanaged` constraint related to the management of 'unmanaged resources' and the garbage collector?

According to Microsoft's documentation on the .NET Garbage Collector, it states:

- "For a majority of the objects that your app creates, you can rely on the .NET garbage collector to handle memory management. However, when you create objects that include unmanaged resources, you must explicitly release those resources when you finish using them." [Cleaning up unmanaged resources - .NET | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged)

Could someone clarify if there's any direct relationship between the 'unmanaged' constraint and the management of unmanaged resources by the garbage collector?

Answer (score 0):

After searching documents and online sources, I have came to this conclusion that the `unmanaged` constraint differs from 'unmanaged resources.'

unmanaged resources refer to resources that are not collected or managed by the garbage collector, while the `unmanaged` constraint in specifies that the type parameter of a generic type should be a non-nullable unmanaged type. Additionally, types with the 'unmanaged' constraint should not contain any reference type fields at any level of nesting.

So applying the `unmanaged` constraint to a generic type parameter does not exclude instances of that generic type from being managed by the garbage collector. The unmanaged constraint only specifies certain characteristics that the type argument passed to the generic type parameter must satisfy.